# Save data passed to a PHP script via AJAX to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array:

```
var arr = [{"title": "lorem", "desc": "ipsum"}, ...];
```

that I try to save to a database via AJAX:

```
$.post("sample.php", {arr: arr}, function(data) { ... });
```

with the following code:

```
$data = $_POST['arr']
$values = array();

foreach($data as $value)
{
    $values[] = '('. $value['title'] .', '. $value['desc'] .')';
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO locations (title, desc)
        VALUES " . implode( ',', $values );
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I am not really a PHP dev, so I don't understant what goes wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: so, basic debugging,  ask yourself what is being passed to `foreach` that might throw error. Have you tried returning the data sent straight back to the ajax to see if it looks as expected?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, it returns nothing for some reason. even with echo json_decode($data);

Comment: so...inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is sent. If that's not what is expected do more debugging

Comment: Show your complete array, `"ipsum"}, ...];` unbox the mystery of `...`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the actual array doesn't have the " ... ". It's really generated on the fly, so I just showed a simplified version.

Comment: @Deka87 I know the actual array doesn't have `...`, I wanted to know the complete array structure. The error *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()* indicates that there's something wrong with the original JS array `arr`, make sure that `arr` is an array of json objects.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul there is no such thing as a json object..json is a string data format and an object is javascript in client

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, there is. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul ok...but that object is `window.JSON` which is not what you were referring to. Beyond that json strings are not objects they are strings

Comment: @charlietfl Actually I'm referring to this(from the manual): `JSONObject = { } or { Members }`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul and that's a javscript object, not JSON. JSON is string...always

Comment: @charlietfl Point noted! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the insert for each value
and you should check for the post content

```
if isset($_POST['arr']) {


  foreach($data as $value)
  {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO locations (title, desc)
          VALUES ( " . $value['title'] . ", " .$value['desc']  . " );"

      // then exec you insert query  -- depending by the db drivvers you are using 


  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. $_POST['arr'] is also empty for some reason.

Comment: @Deka87  well if my answer is right or is useful please rate it